# 16x Presence Short (1x Riser)

Tags: mining-hardware, gpu

I have an MSI Z77a-GD65 and I need to short one of the slots to get it to work. The MB was working fine with 5 GPUs until a couple of weeks ago when one of the slots stopped working. I know it's the slot because when I plug this GPU and riser into another slot it works and when I plug another GPU and riser into this slot it doesn't work.

So, I see posts about presence shorting a 1x slot. I found a page here that provides description of pins for all slots (1x, 4x, 8x, 16x).
http://pinouts.ru/Slots/pci_express_pinout.shtml

All slots except the 16x seems easy enough but the 16x has multiple presence detect, hot plug detect, hot plug present detect, etc pins. Any idea how to do a presence short?

I'm using a 1x to 16x powered riser.

Help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about repairing hardware. It might be a better fit for the **[superuser SE](http://superuser.com)** which deals with hardware topics.

Comment: @Murch, thanks. I may do that then. Presence shorts are actually directly related to mining, not so much about hardware repair. 1x risers frequently require presence shorts to get them to work and it's not a hardware defect so I was hoping someone here could help me out.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't aware of that. ;) Unfortunately, hardware questions don't seem to get good answers here quickly, we just had another a few days ago that has been just collecting orthogonal answers.

Comment: @Murch Thanks for the heads up :) I appreciate that. New here so still learning :) I'll try the bitcointalk forum as well.